# Python: Plot histogram of dataframe with one column as the labels, and the other as the values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns.  I want to plot a histogram with the 'Word_Length' column as the x-axis labels and the y-axis values as the 'Count'

Here's a short example of what the data looks like.  Both Columns values are integers.

```
Word_Length   Count
1             265
9             67
3             45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), because [`histogram`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is an accurate graphical representation of the distribution of numerical data:

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'Word_Length', y='Count')
```

Comment: Is there a way to plot them in order.  By that I mean ordering the Word_Length column bi increasing value with the Count column values corresponding.

Comment: Do you think `df.assign(Word_Length=df['Word_Length'].astype(str)).plot.bar(x = 'Word_Length', y='Count')` ?

Comment: Both worked.  And I think I figured out my sorting issue.  Thanks.